# Storing routes in a file and importing into App.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, routes

I'm trying to store routes in a file to make them more modular. I am using BrowserRouter, Switch, and Route. Right now, the components are not showing up on the page where the links are. I am using Django for backend and React for front. These are supposed to be the URLs that show in the top bar, and the only Django URLs are the APIs. I need the actual URLs so I can link them in the navbar.

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MembersRouter from "./members/MembersRouter";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/memberships/redesign" component={ MembersRouter }/>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MembersRouter.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MemberForm from './MemberForm';
import MembersTable from './MembersTable';
import MembershipForm from './MembershipForm';
import MembershipTable from './MembershipTable';
import LockerRentalForm from './LockerRentalForm';
import LockerRentalTable from './LockerRentalTable';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MembersRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/member_form" component={ MemberForm } />
          <Route path="/members_table" component={ MembersTable} />
          <Route path="/membership_form" component={ MembershipForm } />
          <Route path="/membership_table" component={ MembershipTable } />
          <Route path="/locker_rental_form" component={ LockerRentalForm } />
          <Route path="/locker_rental_table" component={ LockerRentalTable } />
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Django URL patterns:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^redesign/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='member_index'),
    url(r'^redesign/member_form/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='member_form'),
    url(r'^redesign/member_table/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='member_table'),
    url(r'^redesign/membership_form/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='membership_form'),
    url(r'^redesign/membership_table/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='membership_table'),
    url(r'^redesign/locker_rental_form/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='locker_rental_form'),
    url(r'^redesign/locker_rental_table/$', ReactView.as_view(), name='locker_rental_table'),

    url(r'^api/make_member/$', redesign_member_form),
    url(r'^api/get_members/(?P<page>\d+)/$', redesign_members_table),

    url(r'^api/make_membership/$', redesign_membership_form),
    url(r'^api/get_memberships/(?P<page>\d+)/$', redesign_memberships_table),

    url(r'^api/make_locker_rental/$', redesign_locker_rental_form),
    url(r'^api/get_locker_rentals/(?P<page>\d+)/$', redesign_locker_rentals_table),

    url(r'^$', index),
]
```

BaseView and ReactView:

```py
class BaseView(View):
    page_title = ""

    def get_navbar(self, user):
        return 'navbar/nav_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['navbar'] = self.get_navbar(self.request.user)

        return context

class ReactView(BaseView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'redesign/react_dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Comment: You don't have `MembershipRouter` in `MembersRouter `. You are exporting `MembersRouter `.

Comment: @Ejaz that's crazy I didn't get an error for that! I will fix that and see if it works...

Comment: @Ejaz still doesn't work, but thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: What do you mean by `Right now, the components are not showing up on the page where the links are.` ?

Comment: @Maxime The components are to be displayed on a page with a navbar the navbar is there, but not the components that are supposed to be passed in the router

Comment: which path is not rendering the component? can you share the path you are accessing and any error you are getting? Or are you getting a blank screen?

Comment: @Ejaz none of them are rendering and there is no error... I can try to add more code or explain how it works more in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you are calling a `Router` inside another `Router`, that is the problem. You should call only `Route`.

You can modify `App.js` like below and try -

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MembersRouter from "./members/MembersRouter";

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MembersRouter />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And `Switch` you can put in the `MembersRouter.js` file like below -

**MembersRouter.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MemberForm from './MemberForm';
import MembersTable from './MembersTable';
import MembershipForm from './MembershipForm';
import MembershipTable from './MembershipTable';
import LockerRentalForm from './LockerRentalForm';
import LockerRentalTable from './LockerRentalTable';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function MembersRouter() {
    return (
        <>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/member_form" component={ MemberForm } />
            <Route path="/members_table" component={ MembersTable} />
            <Route path="/membership_form" component={ MembershipForm } />
            <Route path="/membership_table" component={ MembershipTable } />
            <Route path="/locker_rental_form" component={ LockerRentalForm } />
            <Route path="/locker_rental_table" component={ LockerRentalTable } />
          </Switch>
        </>
    );
}
```

And wrap your `App` from `App.js` in the `Router` component, in the `index.js` file, something like this -

**index.js**

```
import App from './App' // correct according to location of App.js file

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

You can check and remove the unused imports.

I never tried this way of segregating the routes. Its very convenient to create routes wherever you need them instead of putting all in a single file.

It's untested, I am hoping it should work.

Comment: This works! The only thing different is I kept the `switch` in App.js and didn't do the last bit in `Index.js` but I will think about doing that!